# How to remove new line when record empty in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Sorry if it duplicate or etc.

I want to display record in Crystal Report like

```
String1 | String2 | String3 | String4 |

------------------| 12345  |

------------------| 12345  |
```

`String3` contain 4 `field`, `field1-4`

But my code did not work like that

```
String1 | String2 | String3 | String4 |

------------------|  12345 |

------------------|  12345 |

------------------|--------|

------------------|--------|
```

What i want to do is display record when it has some data, i have 4 record, if 1 or more record contain some data then other record will not create new line, so no space will be taken.

```
if {Table.Field1} = "0" then 
""
else if {Table.Field2} = "0" then
""
else if {Table.Field3} = "0" then 
""
else if {Table.Field4} = "0" then 
""
else
{Table.Field1} & "<br>" & {Table.Field2} & "<br>" & {Table.Field3} & "<br>" & {Table.Field4}
```

Using `Can Grow` and Text Interpretation `HTML Text` on Crystal Report

Comment: In Section expert, detail section properties, check "Suppress blank section".

Comment: thanks, but still not work

Answer (score 0):

one wayout would be using text fields with background colour enabled on it.

Basic idea is place the text fields with background that is matching the report and write supress conditions for text fields so as when there is no data then show else supress.

This will ensure that when there is no data then text field will cover the line which will give the impress that line is not printed.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------

Now in below picture I have place a text field in between line and set the background color to white that matches my preiview.

[image]
Check the rectangle highlighted part at the end of the line

Now in preview you can see in looks like there is no line where the text field is placed.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand, could you show me the way?